# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 orm:validate-schema multiple databases

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've 2 entity manager orm_default for my backend and orm_powerdns for an interface with PowerDns.

if I want to validate schemas, orm:validate-schema valids only orm_default. How to validate my other schema?

Comment: did you have any luck with the http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation ?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched and tried multiple things, but the easiest thing I've found that works is changing the Entity Manager in the following file manually, before running the command:

> .\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-orm-module\src\DoctrineORMModule\Module.php

line 141:

from:

```
$entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```

to:

```
$entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('your_em_name');
```

Both the validate and create commands worked for me after that.

Comment: This works for me. Did you find a better solution for this?